# Kubernetes logs don't print requests output when I use a port in an address

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I've created a cluster with *minikube*

```
minikube start
```

Applied this yaml manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gateway
        image: docker_gateway
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4001
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 4001
```

And my GO app in the container `docker_gateway` is just a gin http server with one route

```
package main
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "hello",
        })
    })

    server = &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":4001",
        Handler: r,
    }

    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

In Postman I make requests to 192.168.252.130:4001/hello and get a responses

But Kubernetes Pod's logs in Kubernetes *don't print* those requests. I expect to get this:

```
[GIN] 2019/10/25 - 14:17:20 | 200 |       1.115µs |      192.168.252.1| GET      /hello
```

But an interesting thing is *when I add Ingress*

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: gateway
    servicePort: 4001
```

I am able to make requests to 192.168.252.130/hello and 192.168.252.130:4001/hello
And *without* the port Pod's logs print requests, but *with* the port - they don't.

```
[GIN] 2019/10/25 - 14:19:13 | 200 |       2.433µs |      192.168.252.1| GET      /hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you cannot access a kubernetes service of `ClusterIP` type from outside(in your case, outside of minikube) of the cluster.

Learn more about service types [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

To access your service from outside, change your service to `NodePort` type.

Something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30036
    port: 4001
  type: NodePort
```

Then you will be able to access it at `http://<minikube-ip>:30036/`

Comment: Oh, thank you, now it works and logs are printed! And you said that it's not possible to access to ClusterIP from outside, but why without NodePort or Ingress I'm able to make requests to http://<minikube-ip>:4001 and get responses?

Comment: Correction: "it's not possible to access a k8s service of ClusterIP type from outside."

Comment: You can learn how service of NodePort type or Ingress works in this [blog](https://blog.getambassador.io/kubernetes-ingress-nodeport-load-balancers-and-ingress-controllers-6e29f1c44f2d)